# auto positioning multiple images to fit using css/jquery

Tags: jquery, image, css

Is there any way to fit the images according to their size (resolution / width*height) like as below:

[image]

So can i do with css or jquery(plugin)?, i tried to search at google but not found any plugin.

Comment: If there is I would like to know about it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Masonry library: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a size based collage of images. This might be the one : http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/

[image]

Also try other search results on google for : **collage jquery plugin**

Comment: as u shown above only width adjusting not heklioght

Comment: try other searches : maybe http://jquer.in/jquery-plugins-for-awesome-image-galleries/jsquares/

Answer (score 1):

Try this jquery plugin : http://jquer.in/jquery-plugins-for-awesome-image-galleries/galereya/

Example : http://vodkabears.github.io/galereya/start.html

[image: Sample from website]